# Should this have been closed?

Tags: discussion

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30701/how-do-you-setup-a-public-minecraft-server-on-linux-centos-closed

This was very different from the question asked. For one it was on CentOS, not windows. Secondly it was to be configured with a VPS. Closing it was silly, even if the TITLES pointed to the same question, they were on highly different topics.

Comment: No revision of the question mentions 'windows.'

Answer (score 3):

I agree that the question is basically a duplicate, if not off-topic, if not a 'general reference' question (although that's still not a specific close reason). The only additional bit is setting up port forwarding with the NAT (if any), and that's not really a question for Gaming.

**Update:** The question has been deleted at the user's request.

Comment: I don't know how popular Minecraft Wiki is, but considering that the question is easily answered with a link to it, it seems that "general reference" would apply (even though it's not a close reason on Gaming).

Comment: @AnnaLear It's probably too popular, given its closed license.